# How to render page with changed text in input fields

Tags: phantomjs

I am writing login form authorization on PhantomJS

```
page.evaluate(function() {
...
$("input[name='username']").val("login");
$("input[name='password']").val("pass");
...
}
```

How to render refreshed page with credentials?

```
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('html')[0].outerHTML);
```

displays only the original content.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use jQuery for selecting the `input` elements and setting their values. Using jQuery is **not** the answer to everything. Plain JavaScript is fine for most tasks and has less overhead. You can simply use something like this:

```
var username = document.getElementsByName('username')[0];
var password = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];
username.value = 'login';
password.value = 'pass';
```

The function [document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName) returns a node list which have a certain name. You can access individual elements by using a specific index or loop over them.

My guess is that jQuery isn't correctly loaded in your page and isn't setting the values. Try this method and you should be able to see the values are added correctly. Run this after the first segment of code above:

```
console.log(username.value);
console.log(password.value);
```